Ubuntu 20.04.6 with test on a flash drive
I just ran my Ubuntu test from a USB flash drive without installing it. I opened Firefox browser, went to strims.in website, and wanted to start the match. Please check for the following link. Unfortunately the match does not open. You can open any video on the left side on strims.in and try to play it, but it won't open. It seems as if some video plugin is missing here. On YouTube the video works.
Is there any way to fix it so I can watch it like this on strims.in?

you can open any video on the left side on strim.in and try to play it but it won't open.

Please check for the following link: https://strims.in/ManchesterUnitedBodoGlimt.php

On the vivaldi browser working too. I just wanna use test ubuntu for whatch sport video on strims.in
